# number of strings which differ at atmost n positions?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, dynamic-programming

I have been given a string T comprised of only 's','t','u','v' as characters .
I want to find numbers of strings with length |T| which differs at atmost n position from T. Also each such string must not have same character at three different locations which are separated by same distance . My approach is using dynamic programming method such that dp[i][j][k] denotes number of such strings of length i , differing at j position while ending at kth character , where k=s,t,u,v .

if(k is same at ith character of T)

dp[i][j][k]=dp[i-1][j][0]+dp[i-1][j][1]+dp[i-1][j][2]-(strings which are extra due to k added at ith location and violates condition of same separated distance )

but i know this is wrong  ?

eg for this is suppose T ='sstt'  and we have to find strings which differ at most 2 locations then strings which do not have same character at three different location separated by same distance are 'tstt', 'ssts' and etc

Comment: This is [a problem from the ongoing CodeChef April Challenge](https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/DEVGOSTR). Please see [our policy on contest problems](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy).